# Flutter_html plugin font size is not correct

Tags: html, flutter, tags, flutter-html

I am using version 3.0.0-alpha.6 of flutter_html plugin in my project. While the HTML tags are showing properly in the simulator as below
[image: simulatör picture]

on real device it shows as below

[image: real device picture]

This is my code

```dart
PageView.builder(
  onPageChanged: (value) {
    onboardingController.activePage.value = value;
  },
  physics: onboardingController.activePage.value + 1 ==
          onboardingController
              .contentList[0].childContents?.length
      ? const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()
      : null,
  controller: onboardingController.pagecontroller,
  itemCount: onboardingController
      .contentList[0].childContents?.length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Html(
      data: onboardingController
          .contentList[0].childContents![index].details
          .toString(),
    );
  },
),
```

where am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am the author of the `flutter_html` package.

There is currently a known issue in the `alpha.6` version with font sizes and device pixel density. Essentially, the calculation of font sizes relies on the device's pixel density, which for physical devices is much higher than a simulator, so the font appears smaller.

This should be fixed in the next version of `flutter_html`, but the latest alpha version contains the bug. To fix, you can downgrade to `3.0.0-alpha.5`, where the issue is not present, or if you need to stay on `alpha.6`, set a default font size that multiplies by the device's pixel density to negate the issue.

Comment: Hi, I downgraded the package version to 3.0.0-alpha.5. However, this did not resolve the issue. Can you please give an example of the code that multiplies default font size by the device's pixel density? Or maybe any other solution? I am testing on various devices, but issue persists on the Huawei P20 Lite

Comment: Is the issue still there if you use the latest master channel?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used this specific package, but most embedded html packages in Flutter don't give you a perfect conversion of styling. There are many tags that they can't identify and even identifiable ones don't often appear as they would on web.

Comment: I totally understand what you mean. But I can't understand why it makes difference between simulator and physical device.
Same ios version, same device, same dimensions. Everything is correct but the fontsize is messed up.